# How to boot encrypted drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, encryption, usb-flash-drive

i have a laptop installed with endpoint security disk encryption. I create a live usb to boot linux, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to boot a usb thumb drive from an encrypted disk? do i need to set UEFI at bios or something? I only want to use linux on usb in ram and don't care about using hard disk.

thanks

Comment: What notebook are you using? There's probably a boot device priority setting somewhere in the BIOS. You need to move your USB flash drive to the top of the list. Since it's a UEFI system, you might also have to enable legacy support.